# java jaas realm: No LoginModules configured for jdbcRealm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas

I made a Form Realm like this:
[image]

Db have entries for users(and their groups)

**web.xml**

```
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>TipRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

So when I try to login with a valid user email and password, this line is printed on the console (and nothing else):

```
Warning: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: No LoginModules configured for jdbcTipRealm
```

any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it by change tables and columns names to **lowercase**, and setting **Digest Algorithm:** to **none**

Answer (score -1):

First you must be sure to define the jdbcRealm on the server-config security, it does not work on the default-config(still do not understand why !!)
Next you have to let Digest Algorithm blank (note write none on the text box if u use payara admin console)

It will work.

Comment: I am using server-config security, and Digest Algorithm cannot be blank

Comment: In payara you can let it blank, it will be felt automatically, i think the problem apear when you felt the field, may be a bug of ayara server [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eb2B-uOxNbtgvyL9qPFfSpZxNq3-3pBr/view?usp=sharing)